# Error: Couldn't open this file (content://com.android.providers.media.documents/document/)

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, android-videoview

I am facing some error when i run my app in my mobile.
Error code:

```
Unable to open content: content://com.android.providers.media.documents/document/video%3A9635
java.io.IOException: setDataSource failed.: status=0x80000000
```

This is my code:

```
        MediaController mc = new MediaController(this);
    mc.setAnchorView(mVIdeoView);
    mc.setMediaPlayer(mVIdeoView);
    //Uri video = Uri.parse(LINK);
    mVIdeoView.setMediaController(mc);
    mVIdeoView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(c.getString(1)));
    mVIdeoView.start();
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer own

```
   //use for gallery
private void openGalleryAudio() {

    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setType("video/*");
    /*intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);*/
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT);
    startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select video "), SELECT_VIDEO);

}
```

Replace Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT  to Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT

Comment: ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT requires API 19 or newer! Many apps still supports API 14.